# Concat array de objetos

Tags: javascript

estimados estoy concatenando un array de objetos en el localstorage ya me hace la concatenación, pero estoy obteniendo el índice y no los objetos completos podrían darme una mano que es lo que estoy haciendo mal,
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr').includes(coupon.barCode)) {
      console.log(`${coupon.barCode} ya existe en el localstorage`);
      return false;
    } else {
      let cuponesArrAux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr'));
      this.addCoupons.push(coupon);
      let cuponesActual = this.addCoupons;
      let cuponesTotales = cuponesArrAux.concat(cuponesActual);
      localStorage.Item('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(cuponesTotales))
    // GUARDO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
    
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que cuponesActual es igual a lo que devuelve push y push modifica el array actual y devuelve la longitud del array, por lo tanto siempre devuelve un unico numero. Prueba `let cuponesActual = [...this.addCoupons, coupon];`

Comment: pero necesito añadir como hago si en el push

Comment: El código que te puse añade `coupon` a `this.addCoupons`

Comment: O si requieres obligatoriamente el push, entonces haz primero el push y luego asigna `this.addCoupons` a `cuponesActuales`

Comment: me da error podrías poner el ejemplo completo con push Gracias

Comment: `this.addCoupons.push(coupon);` y luego `let cuponesActual = this.addCoupons`

Comment: ERROR TypeError: cuponesArrAux.concat is not a function

Comment: actualizo como tengo el codigo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136345/discussion-between-pipe-and-sixto-mujica).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organicé el código, debería funcionarte así:

```js
agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    const cupones = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) || [];
    
    if(cupones.some(c => c.barCode === coupon.barCode)) {
      console.log(`${coupon.barCode} ya existe en el localstorage`);
      return false;
    } else {
      cupones.push(coupon);
      // GUARDO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
      localStorage.Item('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(cupones))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Pipe estas?

Comment: como puedo añadir una clase active, cuando ya existe en el localstorage? en el HTML

Comment: añadir una clase active a que? y en que momento?
Mejor realiza otra pregunta con tu siguiente duda.

Comment: ya lo resolví, podemos seguir en el chat, tengo otro problema